# Collecting stderr in memory with subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to collect stderr in memory, instead of directly writing it to a file or stdout. I do this so I can generated the error log file in a certain way. I found a library called [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) that is an in-memory 'file'. I don't think it does the trick. Here's my code:

```
        buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
        status = subprocess.call(args, stdout=log_fps["trace"], stderr=buffer)

        if status and self.V_LEVEL:
            sys.stderr.write(buffer.getvalue())
            print "generated error"

        if status:
            log_fps["fail"].write("==> Error with files %s and %s\n" % (domain_file, problem_file))
            log_fps["fail"].write(buffer.getvalue())
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runit.py", line 284, in <module>
    launcher.run_all_cff_domain_examples("ring")
  File "./runit.py", line 259, in run_all_cff_domain_examples
    result = self.run_clg(in_d["domain"], in_d["problem"], in_d["prefix"])
  File "./runit.py", line 123, in run_clg
    status = subprocess.call(args, stdout=log_fps["trace"], stderr=buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1075, in _get_handles
    errwrite = stderr.fileno()
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I guess this means that I can't use StringIO to collect stderr in memory. What else can I do, short of writing to a file in /tmp?

Answer (score 2):

```
stdout = subprocess.check_output(args)
```

See [`check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) documentation for more options.

If you don't want to capture `stdout`, use `Popen.communicate`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(args, stdout=log_fps["trace"], stderr=PIPE)
_, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: That's not really what I want since check_output raises CalledProcessError on non-zero exit code, and I expect command to fail frequently.

Comment: Also, the popen call is fundamentally different from my call because now the shell program is running asynchronously. If you put Popen.wait(), then cannot read from communicate. If you put p.wait() after communicate, you may not capture all the output in stderr. I have tried this approach before.

Comment: Finally, your first command `stdout, stderr = subprocess.check_output(args)` doesn't work for me. I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

Comment: @BlackSheep: that should have been just `stdout =...`. Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: @BlackSheep: `.communicate()` reads *all* stdout/stderr and waits for the subprocess to exit. No need to call `p.wait()`.

Comment: @BlackSheep: also when you call `wait` after `communicate`? That sounds like a Python bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=log_fps["trace"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

_, stderr = p.communicate()
print stderr,
```