# Python subprocess supress stdout and stderr

Tags: python

I call an external binary using the subprocess module:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output([param1, param2], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)
```

This outputs an error both when the `check_output` runs and in the except statement.
What I really want to have is to print the output **only if I catch an exception.** So that means I want to have stderr in the exception object.

The problem is that if I suppress the stdout:

```
subprocess.check_output(..., stdout=open(sys.os.devnull, 'wb'))
```

Then `e.output` sure becomes empty. Also I tried setting stderr to None - the same effect.

How to add `stderr` to the `subprocess.CalledProcessError` instance without redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` because I do not need `stdout` at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352163/collecting-stderr-in-memory-with-subprocess-call

Comment: don't print `e.output` id you only want to see the error once,`subprocess.check_output([param1, param2])` and use a pass instead of a print

Comment: That's just an example. In a real application I reraise exception which then is used to produce jsonified error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`check_output` is a convenience function with limited functionality. If it doesn't do what you want, roll your own:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([param1, param2],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
if proc.returncode != 0:
    print(err)
```

Comment: As far a I understand in case of non-zero return code check_output will raise an exception and I will never reach `print(err)` part.

Comment: Seems you you ment `subprocess.Popen` insted of `subprocess.check_output`. I thought it's possible to do that with the default check_output. Just supress stdout and have stderr in a exception. Strange ..