# How to use a `with` statement to suppress `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr`?

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, suppress, dev-null

**I'm trying to use a `with` statement to suppress `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr` individually.**  I found a [tutorial](https://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/10/25/temporarily-suppress-console-output-in-python/) that didn't work.  I'm using `Python 3.6.4` and I think the tutorial is some version of `Python 2`.

[I looked it up on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=supress+stdout+python) and found a few but with applications that didn't work or did not apply to this situation.

This doesn't apply:[Python subprocess supress stdout and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831221/python-subprocess-supress-stdout-and-stderr)

Couldn't get any of the `with` statements to work: 
[Suppress stdout / stderr print from Python functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130156/suppress-stdout-stderr-print-from-python-functions)

This is for fortran: [Redirecting FORTRAN (called via F2PY) output in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977840/redirecting-fortran-called-via-f2py-output-in-python/978264#978264)

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def suppress_console(file=sys.stdout):
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_file = file
        file = devnull
        try:  
            yield
        finally:
            file = old_file

with suppress_console():
    print(1, file=sys.stdout)
# 1
```

Comment: You realize that `contextlib` already include `redirect_stdout` and `redirect_stderr ` context managers, right? Just redirect to `os.devnull`

Comment: But the reason this doesn't work is because you merely reassign the local-variable `old_file`. You need to change the attributes of `sys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this:

```
class Suppress:
    def __init__(self, *, suppress_stdout=False, suppress_stderr=False):
        self.suppress_stdout = suppress_stdout
        self.suppress_stderr = suppress_stderr
        self.original_stdout = None
        self.original_stderr = None

    def __enter__(self):
        import sys, os
        devnull = open(os.devnull, "w")

        # Suppress streams
        if self.suppress_stdout:
            self.original_stdout = sys.stdout
            sys.stdout = devnull

        if self.suppress_stderr:
            self.original_stderr = sys.stderr
            sys.stderr = devnull

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import sys
        # Restore streams
        if self.suppress_stdout:
            sys.stdout = self.original_stdout

        if self.suppress_stderr:
            sys.stderr = self.original_stderr
```

**Example:**

```
import sys
print("Before")
with Suppress(suppress_stdout=True):
    print("Inside")
print("After")

print("Before", file=sys.stderr)
with Suppress(suppress_stderr=True):
    print("Inside", file=sys.stderr)
print("After", file=sys.stderr)
```

**Output**:

```
Before
After
Before
After
```

Notes:

- I put my imports inside methods for cleanliness, but usually this would be inside a module file with imports at the top.
- Suppressing stderr is risky, especially because of the way I'm (not) handling exceptions in the `__exit__` method.  You might look into crafting a more robust exit method.

Comment: Wow, this coding has great style.  Thanks a lot for this.  I'm not really sure how with statements and objects that are compatible with statements work but this definitely gives me some insight.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following one:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, contextmanager
import os


@contextmanager
def suppress():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as null:
        with redirect_stdout(null):
            yield
```

test:

```
print("qwer")
with suppress():
    print("asdf")
print("ghjk")
# qwer
# ghjk
```

## update

A better one:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr, contextmanager, ExitStack
import os

@contextmanager
def suppress(out=True, err=False):
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        with open(os.devnull, "w") as null:
            if out:
                stack.enter_context(redirect_stdout(null))
            if err:
                stack.enter_context(redirect_stderr(null))
            yield
```

Comment: This doesn't work for silencing output from a bound C++ library, this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954769/4756725